# jQuery plugin method that doesn't take an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm authoring a jQuery plugin in which one of the methods that I'd like to write will not take a selector argument and does not need to pass an element. I'd like it to be available by a call like `$.myMethod()` like the built in `$.ajax()` method. Up to now I've tried something like

```
$.fn.myMethod(options) {
     console.log("I've been called");
}
```

This works when I try `$('.a_selector').myMethod()` but not when I try `$.myMethod()`.

Is this doable with a jQuery plugin or is it only available for interal functions.

The purpose of this method is to perform an action on some data that is stored in jQuery.data. I recognize that they jQuery.data is associated with an element, but in this case I've hard coded it to the body element to make things easier for the end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that are members of `$.fn` apply to jQuery objects, not to the `$` object itself. If you want to create such a method, you only have to write:

```
$.yourMethod = function() {
    // Do something.
};
```

Now you can call it without a jQuery object:

```
$.yourMethod();
```

Comment: The blatant obviousness of this is smacking me in the face... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An elaborate way of declaring such a function can be

```
$.extend({myMethodA:function(){
                            //Do something
                            },
          myMethodB:function(){
                        //Do something else
                                }       
                 });
```